# @Input always undefined

Tags: angular, angular5

I am passing ids into a child component in order to filter the whole set in that component. For that I am using @Input to define the id to filter upon.

```
<div *ngIf="exerciseLength > 0">
   <exercise [course]="Course" [filter-by-exercise-id]=""></exercise>
</div>
```

In my child component I have the following

```
@Input() course: Course;
@Input() filterByExerciseId;

exercises: Exercise[];    

constructor(//services) {
    // Initialize array to avoid undefined errors
    this.exercises = [];
}

ngOnInit() {
        if (this.course.exercises) {
            // exercises already included in data, no need to load them
            this.initExercises(this.course.exercises);
        } else {
            this.courseExerciseService.query(this.course.id, {
                courseId: this.course.id,
                withLtiOutcomeUrlExisting: true
            }).subscribe((exercises) => {
                this.initExercises(exercises);
            });
        }
    }

initExercises(exercises) {
        console.log('filter ' + this.filterByExerciseId);
        if (this.filterByExerciseId) {
            exercises = exercises.filter((exercise) => exercise.id === this.filterByExerciseId);
        }

     //more stuff
    }
```

But whatever I do my filterIds are undefined.

I tried passing in values directly:

```
[filter-by-exercise-id]="2"
```

Or declaring a variable in the parent component and pass that one in

Parent definition:

```
ids: number = 2;
```

Html:

```
[filter-by-exercise-id]="ids"
```

The filtering itselfs work it's just that the Input isn't set. 
Any idea where I am stuck?

Since @Input gets defined in ngOnInit() it should be availiable right?

And the other @Input of course works just fine.

Comment: I might be wrong, but shouldn't you use the same name, as in doing `<exercise [course]="Course" [filterByExerciseId]=""></exercise>`?

Comment: thx @DanDumitru too ;)

Comment: @DanDumitru  your right they should be the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is you cannot use @input with name like    `@Input() filter-by-exercise-id;` you should use

```
   @Input() filterByExerciseId;
```

and HTML as,

```
  <exercise [course]="Course" [filterByExerciseId]=ids></exercise>
```

Comment: The typical case of not seeing it after checking everything 100 time